# Escrever numa label quando esta carrega com a form

Tags: c#, sql, timer

Boas, tenho um programa que necessita que eu escreva com recurso a labels, no entanto estas só funcionam, e realmente escrevem quando são clicadas, gostaria que alguém me explicasse como deveria de proceder para conseguir então escrever assim que a form é carregada:

EDIT: Basicamente como disse estou a tentar escrever numa label dados que tirei de uma BD no entanto este só são escritos quando eu clico nas labels, gostaria que fossem escritos assim que a form e about ou seja carregada, fica o codigo

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\wintouch;Initial        Catalog=bbl;User ID=sa;Password=Pa$$w0rd");
    conn.Open();
    string info = ""; // open connection and creat the string that contains info



        //-----------------------------------------------------------//

        Timer timer1 = new Timer();

        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(label4_load);
        timer1.Interval = 55;
        timer1.Enabled = true;


        string varsql = "SELECT sum(merc1)/2 as total FROM wgcdoccab where tipodoc ='FSS' and serie='1' and contribuinte='999999990' and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())),120)"; //division query 


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(varsql, conn);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {

            info = dr["total"].ToString().TrimEnd() + "," + "\r"; // search the database?

        }

        label4.Text = info; //display information on hte label
        label4.Text = string.Format("new_text {0}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()); 
        conn.Close();

        timer1.Stop();
    }`
```

Comment: Tente dar mais detalhes sobre sua dúvida, postar um código e/ou imagem que pode ajudar na solução do problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando se cria um Form, o sistema cria um Construtor dele assim:

```
.....
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   label1.Text = "Escreva o que tu quiseres aqui";// Faça isso em baixo do InitializeComponent();
}
```

Só isso e mais nada.

Comment: Sim, eu depois reparei que era uma coisa parva, estava a mexer no codigo a tanto tempo seguido que acabei por nao reparar que estava a escrever no Labelx_load em vez do Fromx_load, erro meu mas obrigado!